# search unique URL

Tags: string, algorithm, hash, string-search

Given a set of 1 million (very large) no. of URL's. Find the "first" "unique" URL from the list.

My Approach: Build a hash using perfect hashing function, that can help. But my question is to hash large data is not possible., then how can I solve this question.

Is there any method to do inplace?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, Frerich. Actually I am preparing for an interview. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: You should accept some answers if you found them useful.

Comment: yes, Airza,  but now a conversation is going on with Freich. After that i accepted his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an input list of `["c","a","b","a","c"]`, my first approach would be:

1. Convert the list of URLs into a list of tuples which associates each element which its position in the list. Now you have `[(0,"c"),(1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3,"a"),(4,"c")]`.
2. Sort the list lexicographically by the second tuple element (the URL). Now you have `[(1,"a"),(3,"a"),(2,"b"),(0,"c"),(4,"c")]`.
3. Group sequences of subsequent equal tuples (a tuple is equal if the second element equals) into sub-lists. Now you have `[[(1,"a"),(3,"a")],[(2,"b")],[(0,"c"),(4,"c")]]`.
4. Filter the list so that you only have lists of length 1. Now you have `[[(2,"b")]]`.
5. If the resulting list is empty, there is no unique URL in the list. If it is non-empty, Sort the list by the first tuple element (the position in the string). In this case, you get the same list back - `[[(2,"b")]]`.
6. take the first element of the list. Now you have `[(2,"b")]`.
7. The (*only*) tuple in this list tells you the first unique URL, and the position in the input list: it's the URL `b` at position `2` in the input list.

Comment: but Frerich, I think you tried to implement Map/Reduce concept.
First map, then sort, then make pair.

Comment: But this can't help, This may possible that Z comes first, A comes last, both occurs only one time.
But after sorting A comes before than Z.
and gives anser as A, but actually answer is Z

Comment: @jhamb: So? I was thinking of Haskell while writing this algorithm (that's why the list/tuple notation is like that). I think it would be rather straightforward to implement and I suspect that Haskell's lazyness could make this reasonably efficient, too.

Comment: @jhamb: No, that's why in step (5) you sort the list of unique characters again, this time by their position (the first tuple element), so e.g. `[(2,"a"),(0,"z")]` becomes `[(0,"z"),(2,"a")]`.

Comment: So, which data structure that you use to implement this?
To check URL is it necessary to parse URL?